What are the main steps for proving the soundness of zk-SNARKs?
I’m currently researching zero-knowledge proofs, specifically zk-SNARKs, and I’m interested in understanding the process of proving their soundness.
Could someone outline the main steps or provide an overview of the approach to prove soundness for these zk protocols? I am particularly interested in the theoretical aspects and any standard techniques used in this process.
Thank you!

Hey @geoffroy-couteau , do you have any insights on proving the soundness of zk protocols? I’d appreciate your expertise!
